# sqoop import into hbase no records written

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop

### I'm currently using the Cloudera CDH4 VM.

Everything appears to be working. Below is my output. The import claims to be successful, however no records are written. I've attach the output from the import. 
[

```
cloudera@ap00134-vip ~]$ hbase shell
12/11/26 18:53:41 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.92.1-cdh4.1.1, rUnknown, Tue Oct 16 12:01:17 PDT 2012

hbase(main):001:0>

[cloudera@ap00134-vip ~]$ sqoop version
Sqoop 1.4.1-cdh4.1.1
git commit id b0c34454234e5246b4ef345694d7e1a5904f00fe
Compiled by jenkins on Tue Oct 16 12:17:51 PDT 2012
[cloudera@ap00134-vip ~]$

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//154.11.169.116:1521/bigdata  --table BIGDATA_SMALL_RAW --username test --hbase-create-table --hbase-table t1 --column-family cf --columns DSERVER_COMPUTER --hbase-row-key ROWKEY -m 1

12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.x86_64
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=cloudera
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13b2fc047340058, negotiated timeout = 40000
12/11/26 18:41:12 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 29089@ap00134-vip.osc.tac.net
12/11/26 18:41:13 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=catalogtracker-on-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@71257687
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13b2fc047340059, negotiated timeout = 40000
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 29089@ap00134-vip.osc.tac.net
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13b2fc047340059 closed
12/11/26 18:41:13 INFO mapreduce.HBaseImportJob: Creating missing HBase table t1
12/11/26 18:41:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
12/11/26 18:41:17 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.classpath.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.classpath.files
12/11/26 18:41:17 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files
12/11/26 18:41:17 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
12/11/26 18:41:17 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files.timestamps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.timestamps
12/11/26 18:41:17 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
12/11/26 18:41:18 INFO mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate: Submitted application application_1353715862141_0011 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
12/11/26 18:41:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ap00134-vip.osc.tac.net:8088/proxy/application_1353715862141_0011/
12/11/26 18:41:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1353715862141_0011
12/11/26 18:41:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1353715862141_0011 running in uber mode : false
12/11/26 18:41:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/11/26 18:41:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/11/26 18:41:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1353715862141_0011 completed successfully
12/11/26 18:41:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 27
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=120
                FILE: Number of bytes written=93711
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=1
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Other local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=182000
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=21
                Map output records=21
                Input split bytes=87
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=93
                CPU time spent (ms)=1910
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=140869632
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=721960960
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=126877696
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
12/11/26 18:41:50 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 36.6957 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
12/11/26 18:41:51 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 21 records.

hbase(main):005:0> scan '.META.'
ROW                                                  COLUMN+CELL
 t1,,1353973273247.a173f168bb6ffabbcf78837cd3f5234b. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1353973273268, value={NAME => 't1,,1353973273247.a173f168bb6ffabbcf78837cd3f5234b.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCOD
                                                     ED => a173f168bb6ffabbcf78837cd3f5234b,}
 t1,,1353973273247.a173f168bb6ffabbcf78837cd3f5234b. column=info:server, timestamp=1353973273287, value=ap00134-vip.osc.tac.net:56831
 t1,,1353973273247.a173f168bb6ffabbcf78837cd3f5234b. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1353973273287, value=1353715834683
1 row(s) in 0.0140 seconds

hbase(main):006:0> scan 't1'
ROW                                                  COLUMN+CELL
0 row(s) in 0.0160 seconds

hbase(main):007:0>
```

Comment: did you try describe 't1' in hbase shell? what was the output? again try count 't1'?

Answer (score 1):

I have written as follow it worked for me

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://(hostname or IP);database=dbname;username=sa;password=sqlserver"  --table DimCustomer --hbase-create-table --hbase-table "HbasetableName" --column-family cf  --hbase-row-key "Primary key column of table" -m 1